# cannot convert from 'IEnumerable' to 'IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

```
[TestMethod]
public async void  Select_getallTask()
{

    //Arrange
    IEnumerable<TaskToDo> list = new List<TaskToDo>();
                


    var mockrepo = new Mock<ITaskToDoRepository>();
      mockrepo.Setup(x => x.GetTasks()).Returns(list);

    //Act

    var data = mockrepo.Object.GetTasks();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(data, list);
}
```

this gives me error on

```
mockrepo.Setup(x => x.GetTasks()).Returns(list);
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ToDoApp.Models.TaskToDo>' to
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ToDoApp.Models.TaskToDo>>'  UnitTest_ToDoApp    J:\Source\RealApp\UnitTest_ToDoApp\ListTest.cs  97  Active
```

Repo is

```
public interface ITaskToDoRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TaskToDo>> GetTasks();
    TaskToDo GetTasksById(Guid Id);      

}
```

I hope you could understand the problem. Thx

Comment: `.ReturnsAsync(list)`, not `.Returns(list)`. Your method returns a `Task<IEnumerable<TaskToDo>>`, but you're giving it only an `IEnumerable<TaskToDo>` to return. You could use `.Returns(Task.FromResult(list))`, but `.ReturnsAsync` is a shorthand

Comment: Why is your entire question a quote (why have you prefixed everything with > to make it a quotation)? Who are you quoting?

Comment: Thanks it solved the error but now my Unit test is not working. It gives me exclamation mark .

Comment: Sadly we can't debug "Gives me an exclamation mark". Please try to debug your problem, and open another question with the relevant details if necessary

Comment: changing from "public async void " to "public async Task "fixed the issue thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ReturnsAsync` in your setup like as shown below

```
var mockrepo = new Mock<ITaskToDoRepository>();
                  mockrepo.Setup(x => x.GetTasks()).ReturnsAsync(list);
```

as your method `GetTasks` is type of `Task<>` return type.

Comment: Thanks it solved the error but now my Unit test is not working. It gives me exclamation mark .

Comment: What is the error you are getting now? Also, not sure what you want to achieve here. You are defining mock of `ITaskToDoRepository`  and later calling `mockrepo.Object.GetTasks()`. what are you really testing with the created mock object?

Comment: Well i m very new to UnitTest, I want to test CRUD methods but dont know how. Is my unit test is useless?

Comment: BTW changing from "public async void " to "public async Task "fixed the issue